# How fix image asset when remove public folder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Hi all I am a new of laravel, After I am remove public folder (http://localhost/movie/public  => http://localhost/movie) I can not put image on my laravel project with asset how can I fix.

First I am create folder in public folder uploads and then my code below:

```
<img src="{{asset('uploads/picc.png')}}">
```

And when run http://localhost/movie the image dont show,Help me please !!

Comment: Inspect the generated HTML and show us the `src` of the image.

Comment: http://localhost/movie/uploads/picc.png

Comment: What is the error shown in your browser's console for failing to load resource? any response code or message?

Comment: no have erro but didnt show image

Comment: If you open that link directly, instead of the image, what do you see?

Comment: can you help me brother

Comment: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: In your `config/app.php` what did you set up in `url`? Edit your question and add the `routes.php`.

Comment: But when I use this <img src="{{asset('public/uploads/picc.png')}}"> its work

Comment: how to asset without public folder